# How can I use a wildcard on a url parameter to an API?

Tags: json, api, wildcard

I'm using the Dutch 9292 API (which is only unofficially documented), it is the official public transportation API. In Postman I make a GET request to [api.9292.nl/0.1/locations?lang=nl-NL&**q=a**&type=station](http://api.9292.nl/0.1/locations?lang=nl-NL&q=a&type=station), but I'd like to get a list of all stations. Not just the ones starting with "a". I know I can loop trough the alphabet, but that would require 26 calls and I hope it can be done in 1. The site returns JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you omit the "q" query parameter ? ( `api.9292.nl/0.1/locations?lang=nl-NL&q=a&type=station` )

If the REST API is well designed this should give you what you expect.

Pretty difficult to answer without the API doc.

Comment: Good guess for me I believe. But it sounds like the natural way to design this API. (You should accept the answer then)

Comment: yeah, you were so fast I had to wait another 15 minutes :)